# My contact form is not sending any emails

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I was working on my own vCard/resume website.
But I am having some trouble with my .php file and contact form.

I tried to debug it but I had no success.

Here is my form in html

```
<!-- form -->
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="inc/sendEmail.php">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input name="contactName" type="text" id="contactName" placeholder="Name" value="" minlength="2" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input name="contactEmail" type="email" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Email" value="" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Subject" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <textarea name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" placeholder="Message" rows="10" cols="50" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <button class="submitform">Submit</button>
            <div id="submit-loader">
                <div class="text-loader">
                    Sending...
                </div>
                <div class="s-loader">
                    <div class="bounce1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="bounce2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="bounce3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form> 
<!-- Form End -->
```

And my php file

```
<?php
// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = 'someone@example.com';
if($_POST) {
    $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
    $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
    $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
    $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));
    // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
    // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }
    // Set Message
    $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
    $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
    $message .= "Message: <br />";
    $message .= $contact_message;
    $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";
    // Set From: header
    $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";
    // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    if (!$error) {
        ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
        $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);
        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
        else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }
    } # end if - no validation error
    else {
        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;
        echo $response;
    } # end if - there was a validation error
}
?>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here, because it isn't sending any emails.

Comment: Any error message ?

Comment: Try displaying the contents of $mail with print_r($mail), insert call to print_r after the call to mail()

Comment: No there are no error messages what so ever.
It is just not sending any emails.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare type of button `type="submit"` OR `type="button"`
in this case work with form so you have to add `type="submit"`

and check user click button or direct access of file you can check `!empty($_POST)` with if

```
// Change in your HTML
<button class="submitform">Submit</button>
// to
<button type="submit" class="submitform">Submit</button>

//Change in your PHP
if($_POST)
// to
if(!empty($_POST))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php
$message ="";
if(isset($_POST)){
    mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);
}
?>
```

Comment: So what you are saying is i should change my whole php file?

Comment: you may try this